# How do I read a HTML table with mismatching columns and headers?

Tags: html, r, html-table, package

A HTML table body has 1 column more than defined within the table header. This leads to skipping the last column and of course, column mismatch. How can I add the additional column to the result data.frame/table in R while reading in the HTML table with `package("htmltab")` Obviously, post processing does not help.

[Here is an example:](https://www.bundesliga-prognose.de/1/2009/1/)

**code**

```
install.packages("htmltab")
library(htmltab)
bu<- 0
bu <- data.table("Pl.", "Mannschaft", "Kurzname" ,  "Spiele", "G.", "U.", "V.", "Tore", "Diff.", "Pkt.")
#https://www.bundesliga-prognose.de/1/2009/1/
url <- "https://www.bundesliga-prognose.de/1/2009/1/"
bu <- htmltab(doc = url,  column=10,columnnames=c ("Pl." ,  "Mannschaft", "Kurzname" , "Spiele", "G.", "U.", "V.", "Tore", "Diff.", "Pkt."), which = "//th[text() = 'Pl.']/ancestor::table")
bu <- data.table(bu)
head(bu)
```

**This results in**

```
 Pl.            Mannschaft        Spiele G. U. V. Tore Diff. Pkt.
 1:  1.         VfL Wolfsburg     Wolfsburg  1  1  0    0   2:0    2
 2:  2.   Eintracht Frankfurt  E. Frankfurt  1  1  0    0   3:2    1
 3:  3.         FC Schalke 04 FC Schalke 04  1  1  0    0   2:1    1
 4:  4.     Borussia Dortmund   B. Dortmund  1  1  0    0   1:0    1
 5:  NA     Hertha BSC Berlin H. BSC Berlin  1  1  0    0   1:0    1
 6:  6. Bor. MÃ¶nchengladbach   MÂ´gladbach  1  0  1    0   3:3    0
```

As the short-name("**Kurzname**") is not specified in the header the short-name ("**Kurzname**") is displayed with the games (`Spiele`) column an so on. So the last column is skipped.  How can I add the additional column short-name ("**Kurzname**") while reading the header using the `htmltab` package?
In addition I would like to replace the `NA` in row 5 with the row-id/number using the `htmltab` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that help I found a quite simple solution:

1. specify to skip the header
2. List/define all colums thru colNames

   url <- "https://www.bundesliga-prognose.de/1/2007/5/"
       sp_2007_5<- htmltab(doc = url, which = "//table[1]/tbody", header = 0 , colNames = c("Datum" ,   "Anpfiff", "Heim" , "Heim_Kurzname","Gast", "Gast_Kurzname","Ergebnis", "Prognose"), rm_nodata_cols = F,encoding = "UTF-8")
                           head(sp_2007_5)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be indeed a problem for htmltab. The only solution i have found is to directly read the `tbody` of the table. You would then need to add the header manually.

```
htmltab(doc = url, which = "//table[2]/tbody")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful. It seems to confirm my concerns